# Issue with drop down list formatting

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller, view

Code is not formatting the list for a product and employee in a correct way. Any ideas?

```
<div class="form-group">
    Select a Product
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select name="ProductId">
            @foreach (SugarHighBakerySystem.Models.Product product in ViewBag.products)
            {
                <option value="@product.ProductId">@product.ProductName</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please, post your completed code(CSS, Javascript and etc) or provide [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap css framework, you need to wrap that label "Select a product name" inside your column class="col-md-10". You need to understand the behavior of the grid system. Bootstrap made 12 grids on a large screen so when you put a div column 10 it is understood that the rest will be inserted on the next available column to reach the 12 standard column.

```
  <div class="col-md-12>
   <label>Select Product</label>
   <select name="ProductId">
     <option>Option 1</option>
     <option>Option 2</option>
     <option>Option 3</option>
   </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: If found useful pls raise the flag.